# Drawing a two lane highway with a merging road

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to model autonomous vehicles merging into a two lane highway and I am having trouble drawing the merging road. I have the two lane highway from the model library,

```
to draw-road
  ask patches [
    set pcolor green
    if ((pycor > -4) and (pycor < 4)) [ set pcolor gray ]
    if ((pycor = 0) and ((pxcor mod 3) = 0)) [ set pcolor yellow ]
    if ((pycor = 4) or (pycor = -4)) [ set pcolor black ]
  ]
end
```

but I can't get a road to merge from the bottom. The code above is just dealing with horizontal lines but I need to also add one with a slight slope. I have tried entering the equation of a line but I could not get it to work. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're basing your code on **Traffic Two Lanes** from NetLogo 5.3.1 or earlier. I'd suggest you check out the same model from NetLogo 6.0 instead: it is much (much!) improved.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an angled single-lane road that joins the highway, you could try something like:

```
to draw-merge

  ask patches [
    if pycor < -3 [
      if ( pxcor < pycor + 7 ) and (pxcor > pycor - 1 ) [
        set pcolor black
      ]
    ]
    if pycor < -2 [
      if ( pxcor < pycor + 6 ) and (pxcor > pycor  ) [
        set pcolor gray
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```